# BigQuery 'INTERNAL: request failed: internal error' when retrieving __TABLES__ from PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery

I am trying to query the `__TABLES__` data in BigQuery from PySpark. I was using this code to interrogate the system table:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config('parentProject', 'my-parent-project')\
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.18.1')\
    .getOrCreate()

spark.read.format('bigquery')\
            .option("credentials", my_key)\
            .option("project", 'my-parent-project') \
            .option('table', 'my-dataset.__TABLES__') \
            .load()
```

and it was working up to 2021/06/25. The following day all of a sudden for this very code I started receiving this error message instead:

```
: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.InternalException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: request failed: internal error
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:67)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1074)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:563)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:413)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:742)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:721)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Suppressed: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
```

(the stack trace is even longer than this, if needed ask for it and I'll post the rest of it).

Did anything changed in BigQuery? The error message is not very helpful to me to troubleshoot, any suggestions? To add more context, with the same code I'm able to query other tables in the same dataset.

I observed this behaviour with `Spark 3.0.1` and BigQuery connector `com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.18.1`. I've also experienced same behaviour using `Spark 2.4.3` and BigQuery connector `com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.18.1`

Comment: spark version ? & bigquery connector version ?

Comment: @Srinivas I'm testing locally with `Spark 3.0.1` and connector `com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.18.1`. I'm receiving the same error message even with `Spark 2.4.3` and `com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.18.1`

Comment: Is it project or parentProjectId ?

Comment: @Srinivas I kept using the same ID for project and parentProject (sorry I'm new to BigQuery) and it works when querying other tables. But from the BigQuery Console ir looks like that is the project name. Is this of any help?

Comment: are you using bq command line tool ? if yes, can you execute `bq query --max_rows=100000 --format=prettyjson --use_legacy_sql=false 'SELECT * FROM `projectId`.datasetId.__TABLES__'`

Comment: I configured bq on my PC and run the query you suggested and it returns results without problems. I run the same query in the bq console SQL editor and still fine. I only get this problem when querying from Spark. Probably the case to contact their support?

Comment: @Srinivas notice that the spark-bigquery-connector uses the BigQuery Storage API, which has different semantics than the regular BigQuery API used by `bq`

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `__TABLES__` is not an actual BigQuery table, but a view to its metadata. A way to overcome this is to execute the following:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config('parentProject', 'my-parent-project')\
    .config('viewsEnabled','true')\
    .config('materializationDataset', DATASET)
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.21.1')\
    .getOrCreate()

tables_df = spark.read.format('bigquery')\
            .option("credentials", my_key)\
            .load("SELECT * FROM my-project.my-dataset.__TABLES__")
```

Comment: sorry in advance if misusing any terminology, I'm relatively new to bq. I tried adding viewsEnabled, materializationDataset (where DATASET = my-dataset, as for your example) and the query as parameter to the load() method but I'm still receiving the same error message unfortunately. I'm testing on `Spark 3.0.1` and connector `com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.18.1` - I didn't down-vote! Instead I appreciate your effort (I've been down-voted as well :P)

Comment: Can you try this query on the BigQuery console? Also, please share the new error

Comment: as I was explaining to Shrinivas in my question's replies I was able to query the view both from console and from bq CLI. The problem occurs only when querying in Spark and trying to show the results. Is it something you can reproduce on your side as well? I updated my question with the software versions I'm using. Besides the error message I'm getting is the same even with your suggestions

Comment: The spark connector uses the BigQuery Storage API to read the data, and it has some different semantics when it comes to pseudo tables such as __TABLES__. The above code snippet has worked for me - can you please share the new error? Have you checked that the account used to access bigquery has the right permissions?

Comment: hmmm maybe I'm passing the wrong value for DATASET. Given your example I should use `my-dataset` right?